# Mac camera not working even after sudo killall VDCAssistant

Tags: macbook-pro, webcam

I ran `sudo killall VDCAssistant`, SMC and resets and still it shows my camera isn't connected. I have recently updated OS X to Yosemite and it was going fine for a month or two but now my Photo Booth and Skype isn't working.